# C#, .docx file, SQL

Tags: c#, sql, doc

I've build myself a small Windows Form App in C# to help manage my customers.  It deals with a local SQL Database, fetches info in it, updates and adds as well.

I'M all done with the bug testing and stuff, the app is almost over.
I have a .docx file that's generated from my SQL database already ( I had it prior to the Windows Form Solution).

Thing is, when I have a new customer, if I want to print an invoice or a contract, I have to use the app to add the new client, sell him his stuff and everything and then leave the app, open Word and generate the invoice or contract.

It's a pain :(

I'd like to know if there is a way, in C# to just, like fill in the .docx file and print it with the use of a single button.  I don't want Microsoft Word to pop in my screen or anything, I just want it to be instant, just so that the user doesn't see it has anything to do with Word.

So far, the button only updates the database.

I am willing to spend time reading about new languages or anything that would provide a solution preventing me to build another app or another Word Template.  I'd like to work with what I already have available... if possible of course.

Edit:
**What I have : A working app to manage customers and my database
                A .docx template file with text zones that I fill from the DB

**What I need : A way to fill in the blanks in my contratcs with C# without opening Microsoft Word. + print that file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just print something, I would avoid using Word for that, and use PDF as the intermediate file.  You could try `itextsharp` (free) library.

Comment: Well I have a template in which the "blanks" are filled from the information in the SQL Database.  I just don't know if I can fill out those blanks FROM C# instead of using Word.  Could I build a PDF template and add customizable fields into it?  I really don't know how PDF works, other than for Publisher, really.  I'm reading about itextsharp as we speak though.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you need, but Word and docx are such horrible things to deal with and maintain, I highly recommend using something else.